# jquery get the checkbox group with attr name and check condition

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am new to scripting. I have multiple checkbox groups in the form and i want to apply a condition on if any checkbox with attr name is checked. I found many answers here with hard coded name attributes but so far non where all checkbox with same name attribute are checked. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="formbox">
        <label>Contact Type:</label>
    <div class="checkBox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" name="Contact" value="email" class="required checkField">
        <label for="Check1">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check2" name="Contact" value="phone" class="checkField">
        <label for="Check2">Phone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Check3" name="Contact" value="mail" class="checkField">
        <label for="Check3">Mail</label>
    </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="formbox">
        <label>Fruits:</label>
    <div class="checkBox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="Apple" name="Fruits" value="email" class="required checkField">
        <label for="Apple">Apple</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="banana" name="Fruits" value="phone" class="checkField">
        <label for="banana">banana</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Orange" name="Fruits" value="mail" class="checkField">
        <label for="Orange">Orange</label>
    </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY SCRIPT**

```
//Trying to get the name attribute of this checkbox
var checkGroupName = $(this).attr('name');

//Trying to get all checkbox with same name attribute.
var SelectAllCheckBoxes = $( '.form' ).find( $( '.checkField' ).attr(checkGroupName) );

//Trying each loop to check if any checkbox in that group is checked or non is checked
$('SelectAllCheckBoxes').each(function(i, obj) {        
        if( $(this).is(":checked").length > 0 ) {
            console.log('IS CHECKED');
        } else {
            console.log('NOT CHECKED');
        }
    });
```

My code is defiantly wrong and not working.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your code? Do you have an error message?

Comment: no error, it simply do not work. 'var checkGroupName = $(this).attr('name');' is storing the whole field instead of the name attribute .. that is the start of my failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter element based on `name` attribute value. Use [Attribute Equals Selector `[name="value"]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to target the desired elements

```
//Get all checked check-boxes of for same name.
//It will include current element also. 
//If you want to exclude it then use :not(this) i.e.  $('.form').find(...):not(this)
var SelectAllCheckBoxes = $('.form').find('.checkField[name=' + checkGroupName + ']').filter(":checked");

//Check the objects length propery
if (SelectAllCheckBoxes.length > 0) {
    console.log('IS CHECKED');
} else {
    console.log('NOT CHECKED');
}
```

```js
$('.checkField:checkbox').on('change', function() {
  //Get name attribute
  var checkGroupName = $(this).attr('name');

  //Get all checked checkboxes of for same name
  var SelectAllCheckBoxes = $('.form').find('.checkField[name=' + checkGroupName + ']').filter(":checked");

  if (SelectAllCheckBoxes.length > 0) {
    console.log('IS CHECKED');
  } else {
    console.log('NOT CHECKED');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="formbox">
    <label>Contact Type:</label>
    <div class="checkBox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" name="Contact" value="email" class="required checkField">
      <label for="Check1">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkBox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Check2" name="Contact" value="phone" class="checkField">
      <label for="Check2">Phone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkBox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Check3" name="Contact" value="mail" class="checkField">
      <label for="Check3">Mail</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="formbox">
    <label>Fruits:</label>
    <div class="checkBox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Apple" name="Fruits" value="email" class="required checkField">
      <label for="Apple">Apple</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="banana" name="Fruits" value="phone" class="checkField">
      <label for="banana">banana</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkBox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="Orange" name="Fruits" value="mail" class="checkField">
      <label for="Orange">Orange</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million Satpal, it solved one of my biggest issue.

Answer (score 1):

1st: you can use `.find( $( '.checkField[name="'+checkGroupName+'"]' );`

2nd: use `SelectAllCheckBoxes` instead of `$('SelectAllCheckBoxes')`

3rd: `$(this).is(":checked").length > 0` this part of code should return an error

```
//Trying to get the name attribute of this checkbox
var checkGroupName = $(this).attr('name');

//Trying to get all checkbox with same name attribute.
var SelectAllCheckBoxes = $( '.form' ).find( '.checkField[name="'+checkGroupName+'"]' );

//Trying each loop to check if any checkbox in that group is checked or non is checked
SelectAllCheckBoxes.each(function(i, obj) {        
        if( $(this).is(":checked")) {
            console.log('IS CHECKED');
        } else {
            console.log('NOT CHECKED');
        }
});
```

Comment: Friend, your code was giving some error at ' var SelectAllCheckBoxes ' or maybe it was my overall code causing it ... thanks for the big support. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user1231648 my fault .. I updated now .. you're welcome